# Processing - Zoom on clicked area then click again to zoom back out

Tags: java, if-statement, processing, zooming

I have a picture then used a flashlight type of light to only show where the mouse is hovering over. That part of the code works, but now I want to use **if/else** statements to zoom in on the selected area and then click again to zoom back out. Any other way to zoom in on specific area then back out of that area also helps. Really any help will be appreciated!

```
PImage ispy;

void setup () {
  size(1024,768); 
  ispy = loadImage("ispy2.jpeg");
}

void draw () { 
  loadPixels(); 
  ispy.loadPixels(); 
  for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) { 
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
      int loc = x+y*width;
      float r = red(ispy.pixels[loc]); 
      float g = green(ispy.pixels[loc]);
      float b = blue(ispy.pixels[loc]);
      float d = dist(mouseX, mouseY, x, y); //

      float factor = map(d, 0, 200, 2, 0); 
      pixels[loc] = color(r*factor, g*factor, b*factor); 
    }
  }
  updatePixels();
}
```

Comment: Looks like you've asked the same question on the Processing Discourse:
https://discourse.processing.org/t/zoom-on-clicked-area-then-click-again-to-zoom-back-out/17675

Comment: Just wondering, when zooming, do you mean that when you click, the area that is seen would be static, or be moved when moving the mouse?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my interpretation of what you are talking about. We store a `isClicked` boolean to store the state of whether we should zoom in or not. When we are going to draw the image, we `translate()` to the mouse, then we `scale()`, then we `translate()` back the same amount that we moved before, but in the opposite direction. What this does is it does the scale transform around the mouse position.

One thing that I couldn't find a way around way your way of updating the pixels directly from the image and the flashlight effect. What the program is doing instead is using your method to make a mask image and applying that to a `PGraphics` object. Another thing that I noticed is that when just rendering straight to the screen, there is considerable lag from the scaling. Instead, I have moved the drawing to a `PGraphics` object. This improves the performance.

In the end, to render, the program is drawing everything on the `PGraphics` object, then applying the mask to that object to get the flashlight effect.

Here is the code that I have:

```
PImage ispy, distMask;
boolean isClicked = false;
PGraphics renderer;

void createDistanceMask(PImage distMask){ //Takes image and changes its pixels to "alpha" for the PGraphics renderer
  distMask.loadPixels(); 
  for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) { 
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
      int loc = x+(height-y-1)*width;
      float d = dist(mouseX, mouseY, x, y); //

      int factor = int(map(d, 0, 200, 400, 0)); //Pixel data will be between 0 and 255, must scale down later.
      if (factor > 255)
          factor = 255;
      distMask.pixels[loc] = color(factor,factor,factor);
    }
  }
  distMask.updatePixels();
}


void setup () {
  size(1024,768, P2D); 
  ispy = loadImage("ispy2.jpeg");
  distMask = new PImage(width,height);
  renderer = createGraphics(width,height,P2D);
  mouseX = width/2; //Not necessary, but will have black screen until mouse is moved
  mouseY = height/2;
}

void draw () {
  background(0);
  pushMatrix();

  createDistanceMask(distMask);

  renderer.beginDraw(); //Starts processing stuff into PGraphics object
  renderer.background(0);
  if(isClicked){ //This is to get the zoom effect
      renderer.translate(mouseX, mouseY);
      renderer.scale(2);
      renderer.translate(-mouseX, -mouseY);
  }
  renderer.image(ispy,0,0); //Render Image
  renderer.endDraw();
  renderer.mask(distMask); //Apply Distance mask for flashlight effect
  image(renderer,0,0); //Draw renderer result to screen

  popMatrix();
}

void mouseClicked(){
    isClicked = !isClicked;
}
```

In my comment, I asked about having the screen move to the mouse, which is what this is doing. If you want to "freeze" the screen in one position, what you can do is store a `lastMouseClickPosition` PVector or simply just ints. Then, when translating, translate to the position instead of the PVector.

Here's the code that would change:

```
PVector lastClickPos = new PVector(); //Make the position

if(isClicked){ //When Rendering
      renderer.translate(lastClickPos.x, lastClickPos.y);
      renderer.scale(scalingFactor);
      renderer.translate(-lastClickPos.x, -lastClickPos.y);
  }

void mouseClicked(){ //At the bottom
    isClicked = !isClicked;
    lastClickPos.set(mouseX, mouseY);
}
```